# Making Bold Apply to Specific Text

Tags: pdftex, bold

Does anyone use the VerbTeX Pro app on their ipad/tablet? I have an issue with bold where, even if I bold text within braces it just ends up automatically applying bold to the rest of the paragraph. Is there any trick to fix this issue, or is this just an entire app flaw?

Also, I don't have this issue when I use TeXShop on my computer or even on sites like this. So I'm thinking it's an app flaw, but i want to make sure if there's any work-around to it.

Comment: what markup do you use exactly? what you describe sounds like `zzz zzz \bf{bold} boldzz boldzzz`

Comment: So far I've tried `\bf`, `\bfseries`, `\begin{bf}...\end{bf}` and a few others that aren't coming to mind right now. The only thing that works is starting the text as a new paragraph, but that very much ruins my formatting.

Comment: I guessed you were using `\bf` or `\bfseries` so that is user error not a software bug.  use either  `{\bfseries bold}` or `\textbf{bold}` note the different position of `{`

Comment: next time please always show a test document.  You were lucky that I could guess the answer with no information given. Presumably when you didn't have problems with other installations you were using a different input, so your question is very misleading as written.